# Swift Parse how to make app works offline?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift3

I'm working on local parse with swift 3.0

I'm doing querys to get results from server. but if there's no connection it wont show last results we got because losing connection.

so what i want to do is to save query results to view it if there is no connection

this is the query:

```
var query = PFUser.query()

        query = PFQuery(className: "_User")

       // query?.fromLocalDatastore()


        query!.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: PFUser.current()!.objectId!)
        query!.findObjectsInBackground {
            (objects , error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                for object in objects! {


                self.usernamelbl.text = object["username"] as! String

                if let userp = PFUser.current()?["photo"] as? PFFile {

                    userp.getDataInBackground {
                        (imageData, error) -> Void in

                        if error == nil {

                            self.profilepic.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
```

Now how can i save the results and view them offline also if app closed?
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Well you have many options here. I assume you are trying to save the user image? You can either save this to a file or save it to CoreData in your application if you wish. It's up to you what you want to do.

Comment: thanks, I'm gonna save user info, and received videos, images,messages from other users. so he can still check them offline-mode. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to set the caching policy of specific `PFQuery` calls. To save a copy to disk, and rely on that before making another network hit, you set the `kPFCachePolicyCacheElseNetwork` policy.

However according to this [Parse question](https://parse.com/questions/is-parse-offline-cache-reliable-ios), there is apparently a pretty strict limit on the size these caches are allowed to be. I'm not sure if those still apply in the open source version of Parse, but if you want to save more information to disk, it might be appropriate to use a more dedicated data persistence framework, like Core Data, SQLite, or Realm (Full disclosure: I work for Realm. :) )

For the purposes of image files, I'd recommend you manually manage the caching of those on disk, instead of storing it in Parse's cache (Due to the size constraints). There are some great image caching libraries out there (Like [PINCache](https://github.com/pinterest/PINCache)) that make it very easy.

Comment: ah thank you i appreciated that, it seems hard work and i have no idea about that and how it works, Maybe i'll see how PINCache works, because im gonna save Images, videos, Messages such like that. thank you again!